# Migrate old VB.NET project from VS2013 to VS2017

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have a huge enterprise asp.net application that perfectly builds and runs on servers. We've been using Visual Studio 2013 in our workflow. Now we want to migrate to newer IDEs. But if I build this application in Visual Studio 2017 I'll get this error.

Error   BC40004 sub 'PreInit' conflicts with event 'PreInit' in the base class 'Page' and should be declared 'Shadows'.

I think it's a problem with VB compiler version (again vs2013 builds project). Do you have any idea how to fix this?

My solution contains 40+ projects. The main project is asp.net webforms app written in VB.net. Other projects are services and code libraries written in C#.

I tried to specify VB.net version in .vdproj manually. But it didn't solve my problem.

edit: Fine. Thank you all for your responses. I got that problem is about code and that visual studio analyzer has changed a lot in the last few years. I'll try to find out the reasons why this code have been working without exceptions.

Comment: If you omit the `Shadows` keyword then the member will be treated as though it was there anyway, so it makes no difference to how the compiled application runs.  It's just good practice to always declare a member in a derived class with the same name as a member in the base class either `Overrides` or `Shadows` so that it is clear to anyone reading the code that it is not a mistake that the members have the same name.

Comment: That said, it's probably not great that you have a `Sub` named `PreInit` in a class that inherits another class with an event named `PreInit`.  You'd normally only shadow a member of the same kind, e.g. a `Sub` shadowing a `Sub` or a `Property` shadowing a `Property`.  Shadowing an event doesn't even really make much sense.

Comment: When you have conflicts including the full namespace will resolve conflicts.  Like instead of using just TcpClient using System.Net.TcpClient.

Comment: I think the reason that this doesn't matter is that, when you shadow a member, it is the base member that is invoked when done so via a reference of the base type and the derived member is invoked via a reference of the derived type.  When the `PreInit` event is raised, it is likely via a reference of type `Page`, so there's only that event visible so your `PreInit` method ha no effect in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BC40004` is a warning, this shouldn't prevent you to compile the solutions unless you set the `Treat warnings as errors` on the project's property under the tab compilation.

Comment: Ok. Now my project builds successfully. But vs2013 compiles project with this flag or without it anyway. Did MS change their politics in vs2017 compare to vs2013 ?

Comment: They've probably just tightened up their code analysis rules over the years.

Comment: I don't know, but vs2017 use a newer version of MSBUILD and it is therefore possible that some kind of warning are treated differently

Comment: @DenVys They completely rewrote the compiler.  VS 2013 was the last VS release with the original compiler written in C++, starting with VS 2015 they switched over to a new "Roslyn" compiler written in VB.